# openapi generator and htpClient version

Tags: java, openapi-generator

i have a yaml file that specifies my api and I am using open api generator to generate the client , my problem is that it generates a client with httpClient version 5 the library is apache httpclient, and I want to know which version of the api should I use to generate an http client version 4 .

here is my command to generate the api :

```
# pour générer le client
```

`npx @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i swaggerAPI_v1.2.yaml -g java -c config.yaml -o ./client`

thanks